# API results changes

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-rest-api

I am using this rest api in SharePoint online "web/lists/GetByTitle" to get list item using javascript. It was working nicely before but suddenly somehow the format changes when I am trying to get results from the choice field.

Before the format was:

```
ChoiceField: {
      results: [choice1, choice 2]
    },
```

But now it's showing as:

```
IndustrySubsegment: 
       [choice1, choice 2]
```

The results property is now gone. Note same as before I am using this as my header.

```
headers: {
      Accept: "application/json;odata=nometadata"
    }
```

Comment: what you want to get choice field data?

Comment: I was looking for answer why it did change? I want to revert it back which has a property results so I dont need to change my code.

Comment: result is not changed as you can see in my code.

Comment: On my environment running O365 the API doesn't seem to have changed, all my calls (Both using javascript and workflow) are working as they used to. Now that don't mean something is changed on API level, but I would be surpriced if that was the case. Is this the only case the return value have changed or can you replicate in on another list?

Comment: I have other site collection but I was using a different header. I was using this "content-Type": "application/json;odata=verbose" the problem with that header is it has too many meta data. I really cannot get why it change it was working this morning then suddenly boom it change results

Comment: So on a new list, on the same collection using the same header it's also an issue?

Answer (score 1):

The type for the choice column is changed to **drop down** from **Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)** that is reason that before you getting result as collection.

You can try changing the column setting at development envir

- Goto list setting
- click on column
- Under Display choices using: you can switch between **Drop-Down Menu to Checkboxes (allow multiple selections)** to observe the difference.

Comment: Nope I didnt changed the setting of the column

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be helpful, API is not changed.

```
var ListName='Test';
var OptionsURL = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('"+ListName+"')/fields?$filter=EntityPropertyName eq 'field1' or EntityPropertyName eq 'field2' or EntityPropertyName eq 'field3' or EntityPropertyName eq 'field4' or EntityPropertyName eq 'field5'";
var GetData = function (url) { return $.getJSON(url); };
GetData(OptionsURL).done(function (Options) {
  console.log(Options.value[0].Choices);//array of choices 
  console.log(Options.value[1].Choices)
  console.log(Options.value[2].Choices)
  console.log(Options.value[3].Choices)
  console.log(Options.value[4].Choices)
})
```

above code work fine for me. you can replace your code with this it will return an array of your choice field column.

Comment: Thanks but Sorry this is not the answer I am looking for. I know how to get item from choice field, I have no problem with that., what I= I wanted to know why the format was changed. Plus this code is not suitable for a list with 40+ fields, probably this could work with list with few fields but not on big lists

Comment: is your all 40 fields are choice? or some fields?

Comment: Only 5 fields are choice field and I want to call them just in once call to save time.

Comment: I really dont get it why it suddenly changed.

Comment: then you can use or operator. i changed my code. please take a look

Comment: sorry but  I dont want call all my choices fields first and call other remaining fields its not best practice. Thanks for the reply though.

Comment: can you please tell me your exact requirement so may be we can get better solution

Comment: My post is more like a verification if the results I am getting when getting data from a list with choice field without any filter has a results property on it or not.

Comment: if you are fetching a list item it will give you a single value. no array.